# Duplicate values while using confirmbuttonextender on dropdownlist

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, confirmbuttonextender

I have a dropdownlist. I have added a default value into a dropdownlist box with this codes

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLCase" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDLCase_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="true" >
<asp:ListItem Value="">Select Member Report ID</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

For example i have DB value such as 123, 1234.

When i run my webform and clicked 123 and 1234 nothing happened. However when i went to click the ListItem Value they gave me some error

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Select Member Report ID' to data type int.
```

This is my back-end code for my DDL at my pageload.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = project; Integrated Security = SSPI");

            SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("Select pr.policereportid from PoliceReport pr, AdminOfficialReport aor, MemberReport mr where pr.memberreportid=mr.memberreportid and mr.caseprogress='settled' and aor.officialreport IS NULL", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                DDLCase.Items.Add(dr["policereportid"].ToString());
            }
            DDLCase.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Member Report ID", "-1"));

            dr.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

This is where my error occurs. It occurs at the area around  dr = cm.ExecuteReader();

```
protected void DDLCase_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = project; Integrated Security = SSPI");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("Select lro.fullname, lro.contact, mr.typeofcrime, mr.location,mr.crdatetime, pr.policeid, pr.prdatetime, pr.policereport, pr.image1, mr.citizenreport from MemberReport mr, PoliceReport pr, LoginRegisterOthers lro where pr.policereportid = '" + DDLCase.SelectedItem.Text + "' and mr.memberreportid=pr.memberreportid and lro.username=mr.username and mr.caseprogress='settled'", con);
        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            lblFullName.Text = dr["fullname"].ToString();
            lblContact.Text = dr["contact"].ToString();
            lblTOC.Text = dr["typeofcrime"].ToString();
            lblLocation.Text = dr["location"].ToString();
            lblCRDT.Text = dr["crdatetime"].ToString();
            lblPicture.Text = dr["image1"].ToString();
            lblAssign.Text = dr["policeid"].ToString();
            lblPRDT.Text = dr["prdatetime"].ToString();
            lblCR.Text = dr["citizenreport"].ToString();
            lblPR.Text = dr["policereport"].ToString();
        }

        con.Close();

    }
```

How do i solve this?

Comment: Please update your title with your specific problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: I agree with @SonerGönül . This has nothing to do with the title.

Comment: just set `Value="-1"` and it will work

Comment: @Rahul, the error is still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cos its expecting a value of type int and in the case of the default there is no value set and thus it is picking up the text in the option field i.e `Select Member Report ID`

Change it to:

```
<asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select Member Report ID</asp:ListItem>
```

and deal with the negative value appropriately in your code behind/javascript

use SelectedValue and not Text!

```
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("Select lro.fullname, lro.contact, mr.typeofcrime, mr.location,mr.crdatetime, 
pr.policeid, pr.prdatetime, pr.policereport, pr.image1, mr.citizenreport from MemberReport mr, PoliceReport pr, 
LoginRegisterOthers lro where pr.policereportid = '" + DDLCase.SelectedValue + "' and 
mr.memberreportid=pr.memberreportid and lro.username=mr.username and mr.caseprogress='settled'", con);
```

Comment: How should i go about it at my back-end codes after adding the negative value?

Comment: umm.. asp.net web forms is not my forte but here is a try.. if(DDLCase.value==-1){ErrorBox.Show()} i.e basically check thex value set in the dropdown if it is negative show an error box on the form.. I  might not have gotten the syntax right but thats the idea

Comment: I reckon your method is pretty similiar to Kamran Ajmal's method.

Comment: Basically, i got 3 values in my DDL. There are the default values, and my 2 database values. When i clicked my two database values, there is no error. However when i returned to click my default value they gave me the error that i have written above. Hence i reckon that it has nothing to do with my SQL codes.

Comment: well the selectedtext.value was sending a number in that case but for the default value it sends the string.. is it that difficult to comprehend that.

Comment: It works. Sorry for the lengthy explaination. But it works after replacing the selectedtext with selectedvalue.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `<asp:ListItem Value="">Select Member Report ID</asp:ListItem>` this line of code from your markup.
after binding your DDL just write this line

```
DDLID.items.insert(0,listboxitem("Select Member Report ID","-1"));
```

Now make your code as look like

int index =1;
 while (dr.Read())
   {
if(index == 1)
{
DDLCase.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Member Report ID", "-1"));

}
else
{
DDLCase.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr["dataId"].toString(), index));
}
index++;

}

Comment: Sorry. I think i made a mistake. I didnt use any databind on my DDL.

Comment: than on first time when loop enters your code than put that line of code that I posted in my answer and than every time loop enter just add your database items to ddl.

Comment: int index =1;
 while (dr.Read())
   {
if(index == 1)
{
DDLCase.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Member Report ID", "-1"));
index++;
}
else
{
DDLCase.Items.Add(dr["policereportid"].ToString());
}
                
}

Comment: I entered the codes into my page load but it still returns the same error. I also have added the place where my error has occured

Comment: what is the datatype of dr["policereportid"] ?

Comment: varchar(50). That is my datatype in my SQL server

Comment: Then use 
DDLCase.Items.insert(dr["policereportid"].ToString(),index);
instead
DDLCase.Items.Add(dr["policereportid"].ToString()); 
and keep incremeting index++ in loop. Use the code i sent you in comment and modify your file according this line of codes

Comment: Oh no. My eyes are failing me after seeing codes for too long. I mistaken my policeID for my policereportID. I have to correct myself on the datatype. The datatype for policereportid is INT.

Comment: Do you want to show int value as selected text in you DDL or want to show some other field as Text of DDL ?